# What is the maximun possible number of simple cycles in an undirected connected garph with n nodes and n+1 edges?

Tags: graph-theory

Considering we have an undirected connected graph with n nodes and n+1 edges , what is the maximum number of simple cycles the graph can have ? what is the proof ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove two edges while keeping the graph connected. A connected graph with $n$ nodes and $n-1$ edges is a tree (hence without cycles). Add one of the edges, back, and you create one cycle. Add the other edge back, and you create at most $2$ more simple cycles, so the total is at most three.

Comment: Thanks , but can you explain why adding the second edge back creates at most 2 more simple cycles ?

Comment: @NazareneChristianSoldier: Without the first edge we added, there is again only one simple cycle. So any further simple cycles must use both edges. Assume there are two simple cycles that use both edges. Then we can combine parts of them to form a (not necessarily simple) cycle that contains neither of them, contradicting the fact that the graph without them is a tree.